# Python tkinter how do i get a result with my variables?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a program that calculates the result from the variables I entered. But error messages are output again and again. Can someone explain where the error is? Thanks a lot

```
# definition of the entry boxes
Hoehe = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=Hoehe)
Hoehe.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.32, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.06)

SolareEin = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=SolareEin)
SolareEin.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.38, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.06)

# get the data out of the boxes
# Uebernahme der Daten
Hoehe = Hoehe.get()
SolareEin = SolareEin.get()

# try to get the result always end wit 0.00.0
def Testversuch():
sum = Hoehe + SolareEin
print(sum)
```

Here are the steps to get my result. The result in the console is always "0.00.0", no matter how i define the variables. Im just a beginner that wanted to create a little program to optimize my workflow.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Include more code such that the problem is reproducible without adding anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

You use get immediately after creating the buttons, this is incorrect, in fact you get the value at the time of creation. If you want to get the entered value, you need to create another handler, for example, the "Get result" button, which will already receive data from the input fields.

You should pay attention to studying the events at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i already have a "Start" button in which I use the function "Testversuch". Sory i forgot to post it. after I press this button the result is always 0.00.0 Here it is :                                                                                                
button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="START", bg = 'gray', command = Testversuch)
button1.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.30, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)

Comment: Try to place the Hoehe = Hoehe.get() and SolareEin = SolareEin.get() code with the receipt of data inside the function Testversuch.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after ive done this i got another error i solved with using the global Variables, but now the results are the input variables like for example I enter 10 for the SolareEin and 12 for Hoehe the output in the console is 10.012.0                
    def Testversuch():
    global Hoehe
    Hoehe = Hoehe.get()
    global SolareEin
    SolareEin = SolareEin.get() Testversuch
    sum = Hoehe + SolareEin
    print (sum)

Comment: Similar to the "input" command, the "get" method returns a string, not a number. You need to do Hoehe = float(Hoehe.get())